# AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__' on import numpy 1.15.4

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, import, conda

Here the minimal code not working:

```
import numpy
```

Here the stack of error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/samuele/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/samuele/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "/home/samuele/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 3093, in <module>
    from . import fromnumeric
  File "/home/samuele/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _methods
  File "/home/samuele/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 158, in <module>
    _NDARRAY_ARRAY_FUNCTION = mu.ndarray.__array_function__
AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'
```

The version of **numpy** installed is **1.15.4**.

Here the list of packages installed (I don't know if this can be useful).

```
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
certifi                   2018.11.29               py36_0  
intel-openmp              2019.1                      144  
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
mkl                       2019.1                      144  
mkl_fft                   1.0.10           py36ha843d7b_0  
mkl_random                1.0.2            py36hd81dba3_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
numpy                     1.15.4           py36h7e9f1db_0  
numpy-base                1.15.4           py36hde5b4d6_0  
openssl                   1.1.1a               h7b6447c_0  
pip                       18.1                     py36_0  
python                    3.6.8                h0371630_0  
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
setuptools                40.6.3                   py36_0  
sqlite                    3.26.0               h7b6447c_0  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
wheel                     0.32.3                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

My python version is **3.6.8**.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be a bug somewhere in your site-package. Try removing all packages and start from scratch.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by removing all the package? If I do `conda remove numpy` it will remove also the dependencies. I reinstalled numpy even the 1.16 but it did not work.

Comment: Remove conda, clean everything and reinstall it.

Comment: I seems to me a bit too extreme, I will try as last chance. First of all, I would like to understand how it happened. It was working before installing on an environment (not the one I listed) tensorflow. I installed it on that environemnt with `pip3 install tensorflow`. And after numpy was not working anymore. And the environment I listed I creaded for a test purpose and contains the minimal amount of packages....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have mixed two different installation systems. You need to clear everything that was installed when you did `pip3 install tensorflow`.

The easiest is to start from scratch, and only do `conda install tensorflow`.

The more complex version is to remove manually `tensorflow` and its dependencies and reinstall them through `conda`.

If you are using Anaconda, only install a package through `pip` if it's not available in the conda repositories.

Comment: Thanks Mattias. Can You just be a bit more precise? I don't want to do something that might harm my system. Do you suggest to do `conda install anaconda-clean`, `anaconda-clean --yes`? This should remove all `conda` files. Then I can reinstall it. I am a bit afraid in doing so, since once I wanted to remove a program, and the command started to remove all its dependencies (I had to reinstall ubuntu then). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and then check that there is nothing left in the Python folder (because of the `pip` installed modules. Then reinstall conda and use `conda install tensorflow` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to resolve this problem is first uninstall numpy using pip3

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

then install numpy using ubuntu terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

After doing this my problem was resolved.